# How to fix super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want show 3 `fragments` in my `Activity` and load data from **json** in any `fragments`! I want show each **json** data into one fragment, but in my application show all of data in all fragments!
**For example :** i want show article data into article fragment, music data into music fragment and more ...
But when running application, show me this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.razemovafaghiat.tellfa.android, PID: 1865
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.razemovafaghiat.tellfa.android.fragments.free_fragment and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
  at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:67)
  at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:136)
  at com.razemovafaghiat.tellfa.android.fragments.free_fragment.onResume(free_fragment.java:83)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2020)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1107)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityT
06-06 17:23:29.721 1865-3617/com.razemovafaghiat.tellfa.android E/error: org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
06-06 17:23:30.350 1865-3755/com.razemovafaghiat.tellfa.android E/error: org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
```

**MyEvent code:**

```
public class MyEvent {
    public String fragmentTag ;
    private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyEvent (String tag,List<DataModel> models){
        this.fragmentTag = tag;
        this.infoModels = models;
    }
}
```

**freeData (AsyncTask) :**

```
public class freeDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = freeServer_IP.getFreeIP();

    public void getFreeDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "limit=10");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "limit=10")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("result");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String description = postObject.getString("description");
                            String image = postObject.getString("image");
                            String category = postObject.getString("categoryName");
                            String date = postObject.getString("publishDate");

                            Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + image);
                            Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new DataModel(id, title, description, category, date, image));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error2", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

            //Stop Progress
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(new MyEvent("forfragment1", infoModels));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**paidData (AsyncTask) :**

```
public class paidDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = paidServer_IP.getPaidIP();

    public void getPaidDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "limit=10");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            //infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

            // Initiate Progress
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "limit=10")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("result");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String description = postObject.getString("full_description");
                            String image = postObject.getString("image");
                            String category = postObject.getString("categoryName");
                            String date = postObject.getString("publishDate");

                            Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post Desc: " + description);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + image);
                            Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new DataModel(id, title, description, category, date, image));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error2", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Stop Progress
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(new MyEvent("forfragment2", infoModels));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**free Fragment :**

```
public class free_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private free_recycler_adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_free_layout, container, false);

        context = getContext();

/*        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }*/
        LoadData();

        ///----- RecyclerView -----
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new free_recycler_adapter(context, dataModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return view;
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event, List<DataModel> mainInfoModels) {
/*        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            //mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }*/
        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment1")) {
            mAdapter.add(mainInfoModels);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        freeDataInfo dataInfo = new freeDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getFreeDataInfo(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**paid fragment :**

```
public class paid_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private paid_recycler_adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paid_layout, container, false);

        context = getContext();

/*        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }*/

        LoadData();

        ///----- RecyclerView -----
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.voice_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new paid_recycler_adapter(context, dataModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event, List<DataModel> mainInfoModels) {
/*        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            //mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }*/

        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment2")) {
            mAdapter.add(mainInfoModels);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        paidDataInfo dataInfo = new paidDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getPaidDataInfo(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

How can i fix this problem? Thanks all <3

Comment: check that you imported the correct `@Subscribe` annotation. maybe you have multiple on your classpath and imported a wrong one.

Comment: correction: your on Event has two parameters. it should only have the event parameter. not the list.

Comment: @Dodge, can you send me code? please

Comment: Event Buses are for triggering events ,Not for sending data .Get rid of the list from onEvent parameters

Comment: @Mohammad i added a sample. other snippets you have to update yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the list parameter from you `onEvent` method. instead use the List you already put into the event. that would either require to make the field public in your event or add a getter for the list.

something like this:

```
public class MyEvent {
    public String fragmentTag ;
    private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList();

    public MyEvent (String tag,List<DataModel> models){
        this.fragmentTag = tag;
        this.infoModels = models;
    }

    public List<DataModel> getInfoModels() {
        return infoModels;
    }
}
```

```
 @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
       List<DataModel> dataModels = event.getInfoModels();
       if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            //mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }

        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment2")) {
            mAdapter.add(mainInfoModels);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should show any fragments datas on this fragment. but when use default EventBus code show any fragments in all fragments!

Comment: thanks man, but for    `public ListgetInfoModels() {
        return infoModels;
    }` show me error !  please see this image for error : http://imgur.com/kwAVUoZ

Comment: please help me, i really need this

Comment: i fixed the line. stackoverflow did break the <> stuff

Comment: Thanks my dear friend <3

Answer (score 4):

If you are using proguard for your builds. Ensure that, these lines are in your proguard config file in android. (for Flutter project also)

```
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   -keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
    }
   -keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, after digging around for some time i discovered the problem was due to a wrong import

i had used 
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

instead of
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;

hope this will be helpful to someone out there.